# Какое слово указывает больше частоту, обычно или часто?

Tags: наречия

какое слово указывает больше частоту, обычно или часто?

Я мог бы знать если я обычно делаю что-то, я его делаю больше чем часто.

P.S: Please, feel free to correct my Russian. I'm still a beginner...  Thanks.

My question in English:
«Which word indicates a higher frequency, обычно or часто.
I would like to know if I do something обычно, then I do it more than часто.»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to be honest with you, this question does have as much sense as asking "Which English word indicates more frequent action - `often` or `usually`?".  To do something quite often and to do something usually are just two different things and it depends on context, which of actions if performed more frequently.

Imagine going for a one-week hiking each summer. One can say that usually every summer they go hiking. Is it often? Well, it depends.

Answer (score 2):

In most contexts, "обычно" means more often than "часто".

But this is not coming from an inherent meaning of those words - it's rather a "byproduct" of their meaning. As @shabunc had illustrated:

- "обычно" = "usually"
- "часто" = "often"

"Usually" implies that in a certain situation there is a typical flow of events, which frequency can be qualified as "usually".
Now if we take **the same certain situation** and change qualifier to "frequently", that changes the meaning, implying that there's more than one typical flow of events, and "frequent" one corresponds to the one that is the most common - which would be **less** frequent if there was only one typical flow.

Of course we have to compare "apples to apples". "Обычно" and "часто" cannot be compared if we are talking about different situations.